# Can a harmonic oscillator have different maximum potential and kinetic energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I was of the opinion that the maximum attainable kinetic energy was equal to the maximum attainable potential energy which is equal to the total mechanical energy of the system at at any point of time.

Howeverwhile  seeing the answer key for this question

> "A linear harmonic oscillator of force constant 2x10^6 and amplitude 0.01 has a total mechanical energy of 160 J."

It came to my notice that this is not the case (at least for this question). Is my original idea wrong or did I miss some technical detail?

Answer reference:

https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-linear-harmonic-oscillator-of-force-constant-2-times106nm1and-amplitude-001-m-has-a-total/

Comment: "It came to my notice that this is not the case." Could you elaborate? I don't see how the answer key fits with your question.

Comment: Here they say maximum k.e is 100J why is not 160? 

https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-linear-harmonic-oscillator-of-force-constant-2-times106nm1and-amplitude-001-m-has-a-total/

Comment: The answer is simply that many high school test prep resources are full of mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is right. The force that the mass feels from the spring is a conservative force, therefore $E = K + U$. And when $U = 0$ (i.e. in the middle of the oscillator) then $E = K$, and because $U > 0$ than this is the maximum of $K$.

It seems that there is a mistake in the question because $E = U$ when $U$ is maximum i.e. in when $x = 0.01m$ and then $E = \frac{1}{2}kx^2 = 0.5\times2\times10^6\times\frac{1}{10000} = 100J.$

Comment: So this solution is wrong? 

https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-linear-harmonic-oscillator-of-force-constant-2-times106nm1and-amplitude-001-m-has-a-total/

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what they mean by an amplitude of 0.01m. If this is the maximum amplitude of the spring that means that they have a mistake in the question because E must be 100J, but if they mean that the current state of the spring is at  x=0.01 then the answer is incorrect and the answer is C and D.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification ;D

Comment: Wait, couldn't you change that by changing where you take the potential reference from?