# How does energy of a harmonic oscillator change when one shift the center of motion?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

If one has a shifted harmonic oscillator,
i.e

$$x=asin(wt+\phi) + x_o$$

then, the differential equation is

$$\ddot{x}= -w^2 (x-x_o)$$

Would this suggest that the maximum kinetic and potential energy are different?

Comment: No. It just the same harmonic oscillator in a different place.

Comment: This is a homework-like question. You should be able to compute the two energies and answer it yourself.

Comment: *Why* would it suggest that the max KE and PE are different? Narrow your question down to something specific

Comment: So generally maximum kinetic energy is maximum potential. I'm wondering if the shift would change that. IT seems like it wouldnt (for me )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x = a\sin(\omega t +\phi)+x_0$ and differentiate once:$$ \dot{x} = —\omega a\cos(\omega t+\phi).$$

Kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2} m\dot{x}^2$ so it’s the same with or without shift.

Potential energy is $\frac{1}{2} k x_d^2$ where $x_d$ is the displacement from equilibrium. Here, $x_d= x-x_0$.

Comment: Ah Right, sorry.

Comment: What is $c$ supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

The potential energy is $\frac{k}{2}(x-x_o)^2$ , the maximum x value is $'a+x_o'$ , this would suggest that maximum potential is still $\frac{k}{2} a^2$

Comment: Why do you say “suggest”? You know $x(t)$ and can use it to determine the maximum PE. You can also compute the kinetic energy and determine its maximum.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/545256/can-a-harmonic-oscillator-have-different-maximum-potential-and-kinetic-energy

This question has still been bothering me. I'm still nto convinced that it is a typo

Comment: @DDD4C4U why is it a typo? The total mechanical energy represents the sum of potential energy of spring (due to its elongation) and the potential energy of the mass (due to its height)

Comment: yes but the question I asked the question in reference to says otherwise